# Copy data from table of one db into table of another db using query (both tables have same structure)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two database in the same schema. My db is in Postgres. I want to copy data of any table (i.e product) of my 1st db into the same table of the 2nd db.

Is it possible to do so using query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't do it as a single SQL command (at least not without dblink), but the easiest way is probably to just use a pipe between two psql's - use COPY on both ends, one sending the data out in CSV format the other one receiving it.

Comment: +1 This is indeed the easiest (and posible quickest) approach

Answer (score 0):

try

```
insert into db1.table1 select * from db2.table2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in vanilla `PostgreSQL` installation.

If you are able to install contrib modules, use [**dblink**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html):

```
INSERT
INTO    product
SELECT  *
FROM    dblink
        (
        'dbname=sourcedb',
        '
        SELECT  *
        FROM    product
        '
        ) AS p (id INT, column1 INT, column2 TEXT, …)
```

This should be run in the target database.